# Test if coefficient is smaller than 1

Tags: r, statistical-significance, p-value

I have a linear regression model in R and want to have the p-value for the H0: b < 1.
I was trying to use linearHypothesis(), but apparently I can only use "=" and not "<" / ">". It always gives me the following error message:
The hypothesis "total_shock < 1" is not well formed: contains bad coefficient/variable names.

Comment: Consult our threads that discuss the difference between one-tailed tests and two-tailed tests.

Comment: I'm searching but i can't really find proper results

Comment: Try [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+tail*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A3).